# Printvisual CopyCount property not working

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I'm trying to set the amount of copies to print but it's not workng ? It always prints one copy.

I tried these 2 properties:

```
dlg.PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket.CopyCount = 3;
dlg.PrintTicket.CopyCount = 3;
```

I'm using the `PrintVisual` method in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few years messing around with this again, I finally found the solution to this problem.

You simply set the `CopyCount` property on the `DefaultPrintTicket` object inside `PrintQueue`:

```
dlg.PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket.CopyCount = 3;
```

Then you assign this `PrintTicket` object to the `PrintDialog.PrintTicket` property:

```
dlg.PrintTicket = dlg.PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;
```

Done !

Answer (score 0):

You either need to build a new Queue and Ticket up from scratch or you can just do this.  This way will be much easier.

```
var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintTicket.CopyCount = numCopies;

if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == false)
{
    return;
}
```

Note: Remember that everything needs to be set before you click "OK" on the print dialog.  This makes sense, otherwise unethical people would make their program print 1000 copies just to be funny, when the user only thought they were printing one copy.

Comment: Still not working. (BTW i'm not using showdialog since i need direct printing without interference from dialogs). Looks like this property is useless.

Comment: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Printing.PrintTicket(v=vs.110).aspx) is what i mean by building a ticket from scratch.  You need to grab a ticket from the printer, set the CopyCount, set dlg.PrintTicket to the ticket retrieved, then print.